# Error Handling. How to pass the actual received error back

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I am using the 1.1.2 spring-boot implementation.  Currently the services I am calling from Zuul all work fine apart from when they return an error.  For example, if the Service returns a 400 error with an error body, it seems to get translated in Zuul to

```
{
  "timestamp": 1466914349337,
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "No message available"
}
```

So the question is, is it possible to either get Zuul to just forward the response in entirety, or simply at least set the message.

Example of configuration

```
zuul: 
 prefix: /api 
 ignoredHeaders: {'X-Application-Context'}
 routes:
  token:
   path: /token/**
   url: http://<server>:8001/token
   sensitiveHeaders: ''
   stripPrefix: true
.......
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We recently fixed a bug regarding this.

Comment: Thanks Spencer.  Is it tagged in a repo yet?

Comment: There is no release yet. It's only in snapshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have switched to 1.1.4 Release and this is now working.  Thankyou spencergib